# file field not working properly clicking any where in the panel is opening the browse functionality in extjs 4.2

Tags: extjs4, extjs4.2

```
var abcPsnel = Ext.create('Ext.form.Panel', {
        id : 'abcPsnel',
        margin : '0 0 5 0',
        layout : 'hbox',

        items : [combobox1, {
                    xtype : 'filefield',
                    id : 'fileFieldId1',
                    name : 'file',
                    margin : '5 0 0 0',
                    fieldLabel : 'File',
                    labelWidth : 30,
                    buttonMargin : 35,
                    allowBlank : false,
                    anchor : '100%',
                    buttonText : 'Browse',
                    buttonConfig : {
                        width : 100
                    }
                }]
    });
```

I am using layout as hbox in which i am having two items one is combo box and other is filefield. on running this when I am clicking on the combobox then also the browse window is opening,But if im using the layout as Vbox it works fine.
I want panel in which there  is one combobox and one filefield dont another panel for filefield. want to integrate in the same panel.

Comment: Can you edit your code posting as its not properly formatted so its hard to read

Answer (score 0):

There's bug in CSS extjs 4.2.0, you can use extjs 4.2.0 and CSS extjs 4.2.1 or you can use both extjs 4.2.1 to achieve that.

Use this css and core extjs4.2.1 from cdn sencha:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://cdn.sencha.com/ext/gpl/4.2.1/resources/ext-theme-neptune/ext-theme-neptune-all.css" />
<script src="http://cdn.sencha.com/ext/gpl/4.2.1/ext-dev.js"></script>
```

You can check out [my example](http://jsfiddle.net/ekojs/gwnq51gz/). Hope this help you out :D